# JavaScript typescript formData append empty Array

Tags: reactjs, typescript, multipartform-data

I have a multi select input. If ı select any option and send not problem. When not select any value. then send form with empty array. But formData not accept to [].

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('education_level', []); //not accept
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) method only accepts strings or `Blob` objects (including `File` objects).

[`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) is for use when you're going to provide `multipart/form-data`. There's no concept of an empty array in `multipart/form-data`, you just don't include any values for the key at all, and the server should infer that that means any "array" of values it was expecting is empty.

For completeness: If you *did* have an array of values, you wouldn't do `.append("theKey", theArray)`; instead, you'd append them like this:

```
for (const value of theArray) {
    data.append("theKey", value);
}
```

All of the values will be included in the result.